# Providing UserProperties when testing locally on Azure Functions with Service Bus Triggers

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

When developing Azure Functions locally with a Service Bus binding, it is possible to send a request to test the function using an HTTP request to `http://localhost:{port}/admin/functions/{function_name}`
 (see Non HTTP triggered functions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local).

In the body of the HTTP request, the following is able to be sent to populate the body of the service bus message:

```
{
    "input": "<trigger_input>"
}
```

which gets bound to the message.Body property in the method:
eg

```
public class TestServiceBusTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("test-servicebus-trigger")]
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("inputqueue")] Message message, TextWriter logger)
        {
            logger.WriteLine(message.Body);
        }
    }
```

How do you populate the `message.UserProperties` in the sample request.

Currently using the following versions:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs **3.0.0-beta5**
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus **3.0.0-beta5**
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions **1.0.13**
- Azure Functions Core Tools **2.0.1-beta.31**
- Function Runtime Version: **2.0.11888.0**

Comment: If you found my explanation does make sense, you could accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the document you mentioned says,

> The message body is required to have the following JSON format `{ "input":"<trigger_input>"}`.

What you want to achieve is to simulate a Message Object, which contains UserProperties field. Apparently a Json format string is not qualified for this. In my test, the whole trigger_input is always recognized as message body.

Normally speaking(without using admin endpoint) , we can declare additional parameters in trigger to receive [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---message-metadata). So I tried with admin endpoint, didn't work either. Looks like function host only accepts the string named after `input`, despite other parameters in request body.

So admin endpoint seems an dead end. You can use [this code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-portal#send-and-receive-messages) to test service bus trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in Visual Studio then abstract you implementation behind a flyweight facade and then unit-test the implementation(s).

Answer (score 0):

The `admin/functions` endpoint should receive POST request whose body is created as following:

```json
{
  "input": "<your_whole_service_bus_message_serialized>"
}
```

So, when sending your request, you have to serialize your Service Bus message first, then serialize again your `input` object wrapper.

If you're using CSharp, the content of your POST request should be:

```csharp
var content = new StringContent(
   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { input = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sbMessage)}), 
   Encoding.UTF8,
   "application/json"
);
```

Id you don't need the message wrapper object around, and if your function binding parameter is your complex type, you can send only the serialize type as the value of the `input` Json property.

Comment: This does not work. If you serialize the input object wrapper it behaves exactly the same as the first example.